# Can playing in cold weather damage a drum set / skins?

Tags: maintenance, drums

My set is in the garage, and now that it's winter, temperatures have been between 10 C and -10 C (50 F and 14 F).

Is it OK to play the drums at such low temperatures, or will it cause damage to the set or skins (which I don't have money to replace right now)?

Answer (score 3):

The fluctuations in temperature cause the wood, the metal, and the skins to all expand and contract at different rates. This will cause lugs to move, the tuning to change, etc.

You are likely to damage the heads if you dive in there and start bashing because the head's probably gone slack somewhere from the movement. Spend some time making sure that the tensions are reasonable before you start playing and everything should be OK.